# Name clash - have the same erasure yet neither overrides the other in method parameter generic

Tags: java, generics

I have read all questions and answers about `Name clash - have the same erasure yet neither overrides the other` but still can't understand how to solve the problem. So,

```
@Dependent
public class SimpleFoo {}

@Dependent
public class AdvancedFoo extends SimpleFoo {}

@Dependent
public class Parent {

    @Inject
    protected void setFooInstance(Instance<? extends SimpleFoo> instance) {}
}

@Dependent
public class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    protected void setFooInstance(Instance<AdvancedFoo> instance) {} //Error here
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `Child` class  declares overriding the following method :

```
@Override
protected void setFooInstance(Instance<AdvancedFoo> instance) {} //Error here
```

but the `Parent` class declares a `setFooInstance`  method that has a distinct signature :

```
protected void setFooInstance(Instance<? extends SimpleFoo> instance) {}
```

1) Either override the `Child` class in this way :

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    protected void setFooInstance(Instance<? extends SimpleFoo> instance){... }
}
```

or 2) other way : if you want force the overrided method in the subclass to declare a specific `SimpleFoo`, make the `Parent` class a generic class parameterized with a `SimpleFoo` or a subclass of it :

```
@Dependent
public class Parent <T extends SimpleFoo>{

    @Inject
    protected void setFooInstance(Instance<T> instance) {...}
}
```

Now the `Child` class can be declared :

```
@Dependent
public class Child extends Parent<AdvancedFoo> {

    @Override
    protected void setFooInstance(Instance<AdvancedFoo> instance) {...}  
}
```

Comment: It's not a distinct erasure. Just a distinct signature. Erasures aren't relevant till run time, and this is a compile error.

Comment: Exactly. The compile error says these have the same erasure. Your answer says they are distinct erasures. They can't both be right.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I think everythings ok now, I erase my comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want if you make `Child` into a generic class.  Then make `Parent` extend a particular type of `Child`, as shown.

```
public class Child<T extends SimpleFoo> {
    protected void setFooInstance(Instance<T> instance) {}
}

public class Parent extends Child<AdvancedFoo> {
    @Override
    protected void setFooInstance(Instance<AdvancedFoo> instance) {}
}
```

Incidentally, your naming is a little confusing.  Most people would expect `Child` to extend `Parent` - not the other way around.

Comment: I've already given you a correct answer to the question that you originally asked. That is, I've helped you already. Don't you think it's unreasonable to demand that I do more work for you, just because you've changed the question? @Pavel_K

Answer (score 1):

You would want `Parent.setFooInstance` to be callable with all possible descendants of `Instance< SimpleFoo>`. that would not hold for Objects of type `Child` since you would only be allowed to have `Instance<Advanced>` as Parameter. therefore it is not overridable in this way. Otherwise code only knowing the `Parent` class calling `setFooInstance` would  possibly call with the objects of the  wrong type.
Therefore you either restrict the parameter of the `Parent` method to `AdvancedFoo` or allow `Child.setFooInstance` to also handle descendants of `SimpleFoo`.